# Backbone underscore Checkbox passing value issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, interpolation

I have a very basic issue, but cannot see a solution to it. Maybe I need to change my way of thinking. Basically I am getting a model back in the JSON file, but I can't figure out how to convert `true` to `checked`. For example I know the `{{-done}}` is either `true` or `false`.

```
input type="checkbox"  id="chkName"   <%= {{-done}} ? "checked" : "" %>
```

I see loads of examples like this, but does not work for me. Is it because of the way I have brought back the true/false value.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the *wrong* type of Underscore.js template tag, the tag you are using is for interpolating a value and having it HTML-escaped.

To explain, there are three *types* of tags within underscore [templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template),

1. `<%=  %>` - **Interpolate** - Evaluates the data of the property and prints it.
2. `<%-  %>` **Escape** Evaluates the data and prints it HTML-escaped.
3. `<%  %>` **Evaluate** Allows you to execute JavaScript in your template.

In addition when executing JavaScript within your template you can use the `Print` method to print out some text (for example the results of an attribute).

Based on the above in your case you need to run a conditional within your template to print out checked if *done* evaluates to true. What you can therefore do is something like the following

```
<% if(done) { %> 'checked="checked" <% } %>
```

Or you can use the `print` method

```
<% print(done ? 'checked="checked"' : '') %>
```

Edit:

Based on the template you posted, the following template should work

```
     <script id="item-template"  type="text/template">   
         <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" <% print( done ?  'checked="checked"' : '') %> /> 
           <span class="text">{{-done}}</span>
           <a id="dele" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon='delete' >Delete</a>
        </script>
```

Here is a link to a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/avudig/2/edit) using the default ERB-style delimiters

And here's a [second one](http://jsbin.com/avudig/3/edit) using mustache style delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it working with  <input id="toggle" class="toggle"  type="checkbox" <% if(done) {  checked  } %>

Comment: Glad to help, You can accept an answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Bingo, your a star. It was all down to my template settings. I need to work out why mine was incorrect. My html code was probably working all the time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tought I had it, but its simply always going in to the first condition. This is what I have. As you can see I'm printing out Done on the next line, which is showing true or false. Your code makes sense, just does not want to play ball. Would it be due to the script declaration?

```
        <div id="items">     
        <script id="item-template"  type="text/template">   
             <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" <% print( done ?  '' : checked) %> 
               <span class="text">{{-done}}</span>
               <a id="dele" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon='delete' >Delete</a>

            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: I modified my answer based on the template you just posted, that said you really shouldn't post this as a new answer as it doesn't answer your question, rather you can comment under a answer for more information or edit your original post to add more info. Another thing to be aware of is that if `done` is equal to the text "false" it will still evaluate to true (what you want to do in that case is use `done == "true"`.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is that when you comment on someones answer they are notified about it, however when you post a new answer like you did here they aren't (I just happened to see this).

Comment: Hi Jack, Your points about how to use this website are noted. Thanks for that. Still having no luck though. This is my json file {"text":"w","done":false,"id":"ee7b750e-5450-974b-649c-98fb5bd3726c"} . So done is a true or false value. Strangely if I leave in the /> at the end of the input its displaying this.

Comment: If I use <% if(done) { %> 'checked="checked"' <% } %> 
, then this gets displayed for all lines. 'checked="checked"' <% } %> . It hits true condition everytime. maybe its checking if there is a value, and if so then its hitting it

Comment: Did you specify a different style delimiter? because in your span your are using `{{-}}` instead of `<%- %>`. Aside for that I tested it locally with your json and the template I specified and it works, if you still can't get it to work I'll put up a jsbin or jsfiddle.

Comment: I added a couple of jsbins to my answer.

Comment: Yip I'm using _.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
  escape:      /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g,
  evaluate:    /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g
};

Comment: Bingo, your a star. It was all down to my template settings. I need to work out why mine was incorrect. My html code was probably working all the time. Thanks again.